# Java Runtime 6 Update 7 Issue

Tags: java, internet-explorer

I am using an Application, developed in Java with Oracle on Back end as Database. The command / queries in this application require Java Runtime Environment 6 Update 7. The interface is developed in JSP, is web based, and runs on Internet Explorer only. I am facing a problem for last couple of days i.e. whenever I access the application after starting the computer it won't start. And each time I have to uninstall and reinstall Java Runtime 6 Update 7 in order to make it work. What could be the reason behind it? 
The application is dependent on Java Runtime Environment 6 Update 7 and will not work on any subsequent update.

Comment: Have you checked if you have other Java installations on your computer? Have you checked the environment variables after restarting? Which Operating System are you working with?

Comment: There is not other installation of Java on my system. But i have not idea how to check environment variables. By the way i and using Windows 8.1.

Comment: Try this
http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-edit-environment-variables-quickly-in-windows-8-1-and-windows-8/ and look for java path